# Can you use multiple std::tie in variable declaration/initialization without repeating std::tie?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to initialize some variables from a tuple like this:

```cpp
int a1, a2;
std::tie(a1, a2) = tupleA;
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do that with *multiple tuples* without **repeating** `std::tie`, something along these lines:

```cpp
int a1, a2, b1, b2;
std::tie(a1, a2) = tupleA,
  (b1, b2) = tupleB;
```

The above code *does not compile*. I want to have the following *without repeating* `std::tie`:

```cpp
int a1, a2, b1, b2;
std::tie(a1, a2) = tupleA;
std::tie(b1, b2) = tupleB;
```

#### Other types

If I wanted to do the same with `int` as an example, I could easily do it:

```cpp
int a = 1,
  b = 3;
```

I do not need to write `int b`; `b` alone is sufficient.

Is there any way to do this with `std::tie`?

Comment: No, ``std::tie()`` is a function (not a keyword). You have to call it each time you want to take benefit of its effect.

Comment: @prog-fh Thanks, I noticed this as well. I think I understand it well enough to answer myself now.

Comment: This doesn't really satisfy your requirements, but it does seem to work: `std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple(a1, a2), std::forward_as_tuple(b1, b2)) = std::tie(tupleA, tupleB);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to do this with `std::tie`.  `std::tie` is a function, not a type so you can't use the "variable creation grammar" (`int a = 1, b = 3;`) with it.

If you can update to C++17 you could use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to convert

```
int a1, a2, b1, b2;
std::tie(a1, a2) = tupleA;
std::tie(b1, b2) = tupleB;
```

into

```
auto [a1, a2] = tupleA;
auto [b1, b2] = tupleB;
```

Which saves you a bit of typing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I hate tuples.
IMO (have to stress this is my personal opinion) they are overused what leads to much less readable code.
Even in current project when I encounter tuple as a return type, I have to inspect implementation of called function to understand what is the meaning of some part of tuple.

Intention of tuples was to provide a tool to store complex data of unknown type when writing complex templates.

### On the topic:

You can [concatenate tuples](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat):

```cpp
auto [a1, a2, b1, b2] = std::tuple_cat(tupleA, tupleB);
```

but I strongly recommend you to use regular structure as return type instead the tuple.